# Select query takes too long to execute

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

Below is the select query which takes 1515 seconds to finish. Can some one help me improve the query performance by looking into the execution plan provided below.

As mentioned in the execution plan, I created index on `event_type` column in the `USAGETYPE` table. But execution plan still showing `TABLE FULL SCAN`. Wondering why?.

Also what is the `BUFFER SORT` in the execution plan? Is it something to be avoided?.

Note: We have Oracle 19c version.

```
SELECT          boi.documentid,
                     boi.device_id ,
                     bie.end_t ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_LOCATION   ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_CALLED_TO ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_DURATION ,
                     CEIL(bie.vfqbalance_DURATION / 60.0),
                     bie.vfqbalance_LOC_AREA_CODE   ,
                     NVL(bie.gsminfoNUMBER, 0)   ,
                     NVL(bie.evttotal_amount, 0)   ,
                     bid.vfBucketId,
                     bie.vfqbalance_AMOUNT   ,
                     0,
                     bie.vfqbalance_CALLING_NUMBER,
                     bie.crbtinfo_CHANNEL  ,
                     bie.crbtinfo_PRODUCT_NAME  ,
                     usageTypeId, usageName, usageType, usageCategory,
                     CASE ut.impact_category 
                        WHEN u'VAS CONTENT' THEN COALESCE(bie.crbtinfo_CHANNEL, u' ') || COALESCE(u' ' || bie.crbtinfo_PRODUCT_NAME, u' ')
                        --WHEN u'VAS CRBT' THEN ut.usageDetail || bie.event_type
                        ELSE usageDetail
                        END as usageDetail,
                    usageDst,
                    bie.vfqbalance_RECORD_TYPE,
                    100,100,
                    bie.vfqbalance_TYPE   ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_OPTIONS   ,
                     boi.TYPE_STR ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_purchase_start_t  ,
                     bie.vfqbalance_resource_name  ,
                     boi.AAC_ACCESS,0,0,0
        FROM (SELECT * FROM invoice_items WHERE ( ITEMTYPE = 'AR_ITEMS' OR ITEMTYPE = 'SUB_ITEMS')) boi
               JOIN invoice_items_events bie   ON  boi.item_obj_3 = bie.item_obj_3 AND boi.ITEMTYPE = bie.ITEMTYPE AND boi.DOCUMENTID = bie.documentid
               JOIN USAGETYPE ut  ON bie.event_obj_2 = ut.event_obj and
                    ( bie.telcoinfo_USAGE_CLASS = ut.USAGE_CLASS OR bie.telcoinfo_USAGE_CLASS=u'Non-roaming' or ut.usage_class IS NULL  ) AND 
                    ( bie.vfqbalance_RECORD_TYPE = ut.record_type or ut.record_type IS NULL ) AND
                    ( 
                    --bie.event_type = ut.event_type or 
                    ut.event_type IS NULL 
--                    OR (ut.event_type = u'!' 
--                            AND bie.event_type NOT IN (
--                                SELECT distinct u.event_type
--                                FROM USAGETYPE u
--                                WHERE u.event_type is not null 
--                                AND u.event_type != u'!')
--                            )
                    ) AND
                    ( bie.impact_category = ut.impact_category or ut.impact_category IS NULL ) AND
                    ( bie.vfqbalance_CALLED_TO = ut.called_to or ut.called_to IS NULL 
                        OR (ut.called_to = u'!' 
                            And bie.vfqbalance_CALLED_TO NOT IN (
                                SELECT DISTINCT u.called_to
                                FROM USAGETYPE u
                                WHERE u.called_to IS NOT NULL 
                                AND u.called_to != u'!')
                            )
                    )
                    LEFT JOIN VFQBALANCEBUCKET bid on bid.vfBucketId = bie.vfqbalance_VFQ_BUCKET_ID
                Where bie.vfqbalance_RECORD_TYPE is not null or ut.usageType in (u'vas',u'video')
                    AND CASE WHEN ut.usageType = u'voice' AND bie.vfqbalance_DURATION = u'0' AND bie.evttotal_amount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = 1;
```

Below is the execution plan for the select query

```
    Plan hash value: 194770266
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                            |     1 |  5809 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                  |                            |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                     |                            |     1 |  5809 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                          |                            |     1 |  5787 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                 |                            |     1 |  2068 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      INLIST ITERATOR                     |                            |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| INVOICE_ITEMS              |     1 |  1313 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | INVOICE_ITEMS_ITEMTYPE     |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |      BUFFER SORT                         |                            |   390 |   287K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | USAGETYPE                  |   390 |   287K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | INVOICE_ITEMS_EVENTS       |     1 |  3719 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | INVOICE_ITEMS_EVENTS_DOCID |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                      | VFQBALANCEBUCKET           |     1 |    22 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                   | USAGETYPE_CALLED_TO        |   342 |  6156 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("UT"."CALLED_TO" IS NULL OR "BIE"."VFQBALANCE_CALLED_TO"="UT"."CALLED_TO" OR 
              "UT"."CALLED_TO"=U'!' AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "USAGETYPE" "U" WHERE "U"."CALLED_TO" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "U"."CALLED_TO"<>U'!' AND LNNVL("U"."CALLED_TO"<>:B1)))
   7 - access("ITEMTYPE"='AR_ITEMS' OR "ITEMTYPE"='SUB_ITEMS')
   9 - filter("UT"."EVENT_TYPE" IS NULL)
  10 - filter("BIE"."EVENT_OBJ_2"="UT"."EVENT_OBJ" AND "INVOICE_ITEMS"."ITEM_OBJ_3"="BIE"."ITEM_OBJ_3" AND 
              "INVOICE_ITEMS"."ITEMTYPE"="BIE"."ITEMTYPE" AND ("BIE"."VFQBALANCE_RECORD_TYPE"="UT"."RECORD_TYPE" OR 
              "UT"."RECORD_TYPE" IS NULL) AND ("BIE"."IMPACT_CATEGORY"="UT"."IMPACT_CATEGORY" OR "UT"."IMPACT_CATEGORY" IS 
              NULL) AND ("BIE"."VFQBALANCE_RECORD_TYPE" IS NOT NULL OR ("UT"."USAGETYPE"=U'vas' OR 
              "UT"."USAGETYPE"=U'video') AND CASE  WHEN ("UT"."USAGETYPE"=U'voice' AND "BIE"."VFQBALANCE_DURATION"=U'0' AND 
              "BIE"."EVTTOTAL_AMOUNT"=0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END =1) AND ("BIE"."ITEMTYPE"='AR_ITEMS' OR 
              "BIE"."ITEMTYPE"='SUB_ITEMS') AND ("BIE"."TELCOINFO_USAGE_CLASS"="UT"."USAGE_CLASS" OR 
              "BIE"."TELCOINFO_USAGE_CLASS"=U'Non-roaming' OR "UT"."USAGE_CLASS" IS NULL))
  11 - access("INVOICE_ITEMS"."DOCUMENTID"="BIE"."DOCUMENTID")
  12 - access("BID"."VFBUCKETID"(+)="BIE"."VFQBALANCE_VFQ_BUCKET_ID")
  13 - filter("U"."CALLED_TO" IS NOT NULL AND "U"."CALLED_TO"<>U'!' AND LNNVL("U"."CALLED_TO"<>:B1))
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Comment: Just a minor issue: It make no sense to use `NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ...)`. Skip the `DISTINCT`, because you don't need any sort and distinct values.

Comment: I removed `DISTINCT` and created a new execution plan , but still I can see `BUFFER SORT`.

Comment: One thing I noticed that , after removing `DISTINCT` and creating new execution plan the plan hash value not changed. Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: I tried `EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('schema_name','USAGETYPE',cascade=>TRUE);` , but still I can see `BUFFER SORT` and `TABLE FULL SCAN` in the Plan.

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong simply by looking at the plan. No plan is wrong in every situation. Where things go wrong is where your actual data is very different than the optimizer is expecting in the "rows" column. Use SQL Monitor or ASH data to pinpoint where in the plan your time is being spent.

Comment: @to-find The note about `dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)` implies there is still a table without statistics. Run the `gather_table_stats` command on every table involved in the query and then investigate why the statistics are missing. Oracle has a daily autotask that gathers stats for all tables without any stats. Ask your DBA to figure out why that task is not running. Also, keep in mind that full table scans are more efficient than index scans when you are reading a large percentage of data, which seems to be true based on the relevant `!=` and `IS NOT NULL` predicates.

Comment: @JonHeller , `full table scans are more efficient than index scans when you are reading a large percentage of data`. Is this always true or its true only based on the execution plan above. If it is purely based on the execution plan then which parameter in the execution plan helping us to find this. Also , could you please elaborate what do you mean by `which seems to be true based on the relevant != and IS NOT NULL predicates`.

Comment: @to-find I'd say it's always true regardless of the context of the execution plan. (Although I'm sure there's an exception I'm not thinking about.) There are two main reasons: 1) The way b-tree indexes work, reading a single value requires hopping from root block to branch block, to possibly more branch blocks, then to the leaf node block. Oracle usually stores data in 8KB blocks, so reading the whole table that way to get one-row-at-a-time is very wasteful. 2) In terms of bytes per second, single-block index reads are less efficient than multi-block full table scan reads.

Comment: @to-find Predicates like `COLUMN != 'VALUE'` usually return a large percentage of rows. Btw, the use of `u` as a national character symbol is not documented in [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA). It works fine in current versions as far as I know, but to be safe, I recommend changing the `u` to `n`. Also, `IS NOT NULL` conditions usually return a large percentage of data. (Unless you have a very sparse table.) There's no precise number, but as an example, 5% is often a "large" percentage.

Comment: @JonHeller , Thanks for the details. One thing I noticed is that cpu cost (rest all parameters are same,  like `rows` and `bytes` ) is more in `TABLE FULL SCAN` compared to `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN`.  In the above example I tried to remove index from `INVOICE_ITEMS` table and execution plan was showing `TABLE FULL SCAN` as expected but cpu cost was 204. CPU cost for `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` was 43. Wondering how this happened if `TABLE FULL SCAN` is more efficient than `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN`.

Comment: @to-find I should have specified that my advice was for "index range scans" and not all index accesses. `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` is like using a skinnier version of the table, which is faster than a `TABLE FULL SCAN`. But that feature is only available when all of the queried columns are available in one index. Look at the image on [this page of the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e25789/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1170) to understand how indexes work. Most index access is range scans that traverse the tree, whereas fast full index scans read the leaf blocks like a table.